# iOS:Image to string conversion

Tags: ios

I want to develop a feature, wherein user can take a picture of a serial number which has printed in a product or any things, using native camera and then scan the picture to retrieve the serial number as a string in my iOS program. I am not getting how to achieve this. Could someone please guide me to solve this problem? I don't want to know the name of the product and all after taking the picture, i want to get the string of the serial number taken from the photo.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: keyword is ocr.  lots of these posts on SO, lots closed as dups.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062755/ocroptical-character-recoginition-libraries-for-iphone

Comment: If the serial number is associated with a barcode, you could integrate a barcode scanner in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need OCR (Optical Character Recognition), and that is not something to take lightly..
Take a look at Tesseract for iOs, this is a library that does this.. But be ready to dive into unknown realms.

Comment: Tesseract given a OCRDemo which gives wrong result when i'm testing on it on the device. Is it NOT at all possible using native iOS latest SDK APIs as well?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Not possible.

Comment: Ok, Any idea why Tesseract sample given from this link returning NULL always, instead of retrieving actual string -> http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/install-and-use-tesseract-on-ios-with-tesseract-ios/

Comment: I actually never used it.. Only heard of it so I can't really help you out here.. Good luck anyways!